# Problema com personalização no DBGrid do Delphi

Tags: delphi, api, windows

Boa noite pessoal, Blz??

Bom eu fiz um controle de personalização do DBGrid por questão da api/windows 11 que fica meio zoado e difícil de ler.

Controle:

```
procedure TCustDBGrid.DrawColumnCell(const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin

  if (gdSelected in State) and (Focused) then
  begin // pinta célula selecionada
      Canvas.Brush.Color      := $00FFC58A;
      Canvas.Font.Color       := clWindowText;
  end
    else // pinta célula não está selecionada
  begin
    Canvas.Brush.Color := clWindow;
    Canvas.Font.Color       := clWindowText;
  end;
  Canvas.FillRect(Rect); // pinta a célula
  DefaultDrawDataCell(Rect, Column.Field, State);
  inherited;
end;
```

Até ai tudo bem, mas quando habilito a opção na propriedade>Options do DBGrid o dgMultiSelect ou dgRowSelect, ambos n consigo passar a cor personalizado, passa cor padrão da api/windows automático.

Exemplo: quando seleciono varios registro [image: Exemplo-dbgrid]

Bom eu tentei procurar qualquer tipo de documentação que pudese desliga essa api/windows ou passar a cor desses multselect, se tiver alguma solução ou qual documentação eu ficarei agradecido.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: experimente remover a condição para verificar se está com o foco ( Focused ), se não resolver experimente colocar um Breakpoint na linha do If para verificar porque não as condições não são verdadeiras

Comment: Troque  "(gdSelected in State) and (Focused)" por "gdSelected in State"

Comment: Boa tarde pessoal, então ja tentei de todas formas deixa somente dgSelected in state entre outros, problema é quando dgMultiSelect esta habilitado, proporia a api/windows pinta e tira a cor do gdSelected. Se é possivel pintas todos os registros selecionados, ou desliga essa api do windows.

Comment: Isto só ocorre por que api/windows pinta a cédula automático de forma padronizado, oque tive 1 selecionado obvio oque vai pintar, mas restando que tirou focus mesmo selecionado a api/windows já pinta.

Comment: experimente deixar só (gdRowSelected in State) no If

Comment: Qual versão do Delphi ?

Comment: @imex eu testei colocar aki o (gdRowSelected in State)  tambem não foi e não chega nem entrar dentro. E eu utilizo o delphi 11 alexandria

Comment: acho melhor você colocar um Breakpoint para verificar os valores do parâmetro State e assim descobrir porque a condição não está sendo verdadeira, mas tenha cuidado porque esse evento ocorre muitas vezes e você tem que se certificar que está avaliando o parâmetro State na linha e colunas corretas

Comment: Beleza vou testa e ver se consigo alguma solução, mas vlw qualquer coisa eu retorno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu fiz controle e acho que possa ser útil pra comunidade.

Bem primeiro eu criei uma classe:

```
Type
  TCustDBGrid = class(TDBGrid)
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    function CellRect(ACol, ARow: LongInt): TRect;
    property Col;
    property Row;
    procedure DrawColumnCell(const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);override;
  end;

implementation

function TCustDBGrid.CellRect(ACol, ARow: LongInt): TRect;
begin
  Result := inherited CellRect(ACol,ARow);
end;
```

Bom a magica esta neste CellRect, aonde voce vai poder procurar linhas selecionadas não focados, segue meu controle abaixo:

```
procedure TCustDBGrid.DrawColumnCell(const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  if (State = [gdSelected,gdFocused]) or (Self.SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected) then
  begin // pinta célula selecionada
    Canvas.Brush.Color  := $00FFC58A;
    Canvas.Font.Color   := clWindowText;
  end;

    col := TCustDBGrid(Self).Col;
    row := TCustDBGrid(Self).Row;

  if (Rect.Top = TCustDBGrid(Self).CellRect(Col,Row).Top) and
      (not (gdFocused in State) or not Focused) then
  begin // Fix para corrigir as colunas que não estão selecionados da linha em foco
    Canvas.Brush.Color  := $00FFC58A;
  end;

  if (SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected) then
  begin // Fix para corrigir as linhas selecionadas que não estão em foco
    Canvas.Brush.Color  := $00FFC58A;
    Canvas.Font.Color   := clWindowText;
  end;

    Canvas.FillRect(Rect); // pinta a célula
    DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);

  inherited;
end;
```

No fim deixei assim, consigo manipular qualquer DBGrid na tela até mesmo depois que passar por este controle, mas enfim essa foi única forma que eu consigui acha uma solução. Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: eai Kyuorhan, vou testa aki qualquer coisa eu retorno e vlw pela informação.

Comment: Boa tarde Kyuorhan, funciono perfeitamente o único problema que eu percebi quando scroll horizontal do dbgrid estiver a barra no inicio do scroll, ele pinta normalmente e quando esta a barra estar no meio ou no ultimo do scroll, ele já não pinta como esperado. Mas o resto funciono perfeitamente e obrigado novamente

Comment: Bom dia @jhonnytopsapp , bom eu testei aki e realmente esta acontecendo esse bug, bom mais tarde vou tenta obter uma solução e trago aki novamente blz

Comment: Bom dia @jhonnytopsapp, bom eu mexi de todo jeito e testei de varias formas separadamente. Bom cheguei uma conclusão que seria um simples bug mesmo, tem hora que funciona corretamente e tem dia que está com esse bug. Se tu me pergunta o porque, bem eu não sei,  mas pode ser alguma falha do Windows e que passou por essas correções do Windows. E obrigado por retorno novamente.